# is it possible to write LDAP multilevel search filter?

Tags: ldap

I want to retrieve **all the child from a LDAP tree if parent object matches certain conditions**. Is it possible/supported with ldapsearch ?

```
ParentObj_1 (attr1 = xyz, attr2 = 123)       
     ChildObj_1_1        
     ChildObj_1_2

ParentObj_2 (attr1 = abc, attr2 = 456)   
   ChildObj_2_1    
   ChildObj_2_2
```

In the above example, I want to retrieve only `ParentObj_2` and its children `(i.e. ChildObj_2_1 and ChildObj_2_2 )`. Is it possible with `ldapsearch` command?

Please NOTE that, when I am trying to fetch ONLY ParentObj_2 (i.e attr1 = abc) and its child **from root**, it returns ParentObj_2 (which is correct) but **along with all the 4 children** (it does not return only ParentObj_2's children.

Comment: Certainly, just start your seach from `ParentObj_2`.

Comment: @EJP : I want to search from root. because I don't know which all obj will match my parent level search condition.

Comment: So what *is* your parent level search condtion? The only one you stated was the RDN. And for that matter what are the child search conditions?

Comment: I have some attribute filters at parent level. (e.g. attr= xyz).

Comment: Well if parent 1 doesn't have that attribute it won't be returned. Getting parent 2 and its children based on an attribute of parent 2 can't be done in a single LDAP filter.